# Create / register a custom date format in moment.js

Tags: momentjs

Is is possible register a custom date format in moment e.g :

```
moment(someDate).format('L-ForServer')
```

Where `L-ForServer` would contain e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes surely you can use your custom date format..
but you have to make sure that your input date is always in that format

ex :[example](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

in your case

```
let L-ForServer = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
moment('1995-12-01').format(L-ForServer)
```

[image]

But you cannot change  `YYYY` to `yyyy`
and same goes with the `month` and `day` 
because they have to be in either `ISO 8601 formats` or  `RFC 2822 Date time format` 
as specified by the [momentDocs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Comment: `moment('1995-12-01').format(L-ForServer)` without quotes.